# Inject Xpath by Xpath Function

Tags: xpath, code-injection, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to structure my xpath funcionalities, on this way, I've created an xml file with a list of nodes containing xpath strings, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <entry id="A">/A/B/@value</entry>
</main>
```

This xml file can be loaded by xpath variable, for example, GLOBAL. So if I want to use that xpath, on my specific xpath code with `$GLOBAL/main/entry[@id='A']` should be enough to use these xpath snippet. My code output the plain xpath string "/A/B/@value" instead to use it to retrieve the final value.

Maybe my focus on that issue its wrong, how I should to do that? My intention is to separate commonly used xpath expressions and use it on other xpath codes.

Comment: There is no `eval` function or similar in any XPath version I know of. XSLT 3.0 has https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate to do what you want inside of XSLT. But in pure XPath you would need to check whether your XPath API provides an extension function or a way of implementing one.

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/evaluate-node.html for a Saxon specific way, e.g. `saxon:evaluate-node($GLOBAL/main/entry[@id='A'])` should do what you want if you use the commercial versions of Saxon 9 and XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with evaluate-node but didn't run, afterwards we tried with evaluate function and it ran very well.

```
saxon:evaluate($GLOBAL/main/entry[@id='A'])
```

Thanks for your answers!!